# How to address Error When Running Demo Code for PuppeteerExtraSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I have tried the demo code for PuppeteerExtraSharp and keep getting the error below. Any suggestions?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException HResult=0x80070002 Message=Process
> revision is not downloaded. Run BrowserFetcher.DownloadAsync or
> download the process manually Source=PuppeteerSharp StackTrace: at
> PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.ResolveExecutablePath() in
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Launcher.cs:line 212 at
> PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.GetOrFetchBrowserExecutable(LaunchOptions
> options) in
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Launcher.cs:line 171 at
> PuppeteerSharp.Launcher.d__8.MoveNext() in
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Launcher.cs:line 52 at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at
> PuppeteerExtraSharp.PuppeteerExtra.d__2.MoveNext() at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() at
> Learn_PuppeteerExtraSharp.Program.
>
> d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dave\Dropbox\Code Learn\Learn
> PuppeteerExtraSharp\Learn PuppeteerExtraSharp\Learn
> PuppeteerExtraSharp\Program.cs:line 25 This exception was originally
> thrown at this call stack: [External Code]
> Learn_PuppeteerExtraSharp.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs CODE:
> `using PuppeteerExtraSharp; using
> PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.AnonymizeUa; using
> PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.ExtraStealth; using PuppeteerSharp; using
> System; using System.Threading.Tasks; namespace
> Learn_PuppeteerExtraSharp { class Program { static async Task
> Main(string[] args) { Console.WriteLine("Hello Pupeteer Extra Sharp");
> // Initialization plugin builder var extra = new PuppeteerExtra();

Here is the code I used:

```
using PuppeteerExtraSharp;
using PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.AnonymizeUa;
using PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.ExtraStealth;
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Learn_PuppeteerExtraSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Pupeteer Extra Sharp");

            // Initialization plugin builder
            //var extra = new PuppeteerExtra();

            // Use stealth plugin
            //extra.Use(new StealthPlugin());
            var puppeteerExtra = new PuppeteerExtra().Use(new AnonymizeUaPlugin()).Use(new StealthPlugin());


            // Launch the puppeteer browser with plugins
            var browser = await puppeteerExtra.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions()
            {
                Headless = true
            });

            // Create a new page
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

            await page.GoToAsync("http://google.com");

            // Wait 2 second
            await page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(2000);

            // Take the screenshot
            await page.ScreenshotAsync("extra.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you have installed NuGet package of "PuppeteerExtraSharp".

Comment: Yes, that step is completed.

Comment: Can you try by changing code line "var puppeteerExtra = new PuppeteerExtra().Use(new AnonymizeUaPlugin()).Use(new StealthPlugin()); to "var puppeteerExtra = new PuppeteerExtraSharp().Use(new AnonymizeUaPlugin()).Use(new StealthPlugin());" and try?

Comment: Thx tried it and it does not recognise PuppeteerExtraSharp()

Comment: my bad ...
now, to make debugging easier, can you try with ..
var puppeteerExtra = new PuppeteerExtra().Use(new StealthPlugin());

Comment: Thx, the issue is not the plugins, as I get the same error without using them. It is something related to the config and setup of Puppeteer Extra Sharp. I also ran the Node code for Puppeteer Extra which is what is ported into C# and it works fine. 

So I can only assume that Puppeteer Extra Sharp has a missing module somewhere, in the Nuget Package. But as I have never used it before, I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that could be a possibility as some required file or package is missing here.
I will get back to you.